Is it possible for some p-values to be impossible? (because statistic generated by parametric bootstrap is mostly the same value.)
I am using a parametric bootstrap/monte carlo hypothesis testing method to generate the null distribution of the log likelihood ratio statistic.  However, I am worried I might be doing it wrong because about half of likelihood ratio statistics calculated on my simulated data are zero, meaning I never get any p-values between 1 and 0.5.
My null hypothesis is that the data comes from an i.i.d. normal distribution, and my alternate hypothesis is that the data comes from a convex combination of two multivariate normal distributions parameterized by $\lambda$ as follows: $\sigma_{1}^{2}(\lambda A_{n}+(1-\lambda)\mathbb{I}_{n})$, where $A_{n}$ is the variance-covariance matrix describing the correlation between any two observations $x_{i}$ and $x_{j}$ and $\mathbb{I}_{n}$ is the identity matrix, and $\lambda$ is restricted to $[0,1]$.
For my given data set, I estimate the variance under the null hypothesis according to $(1/(n-1))\sum_i(x_{i}-x_{mean})^{2}$.  Then I generate 999 datasets each of size n from a normal distribution with the variance I just estimated.  Then for each of these datasets I fit the $\lambda$ value by maximum likelihood and compare it to the maximum likelihood value of the nested hypothesis which fixes $\lambda=0$.  Then having calculated the ratio on 999 simulated datasets, I can calculate the the p-value by counting how many log likelihood ratio values are greater than or equal to that on the original dataset.
The problem is, more than half of the log likelihood ratios are exactly zero.  Is this the result of some sort of mistake I'm making?  Or is it possible for the distribution of log likelihood ratios to have such a weird distribution?  And in this case are the p-values reliable?
EDIT 1: (I'm actively editing this and will remove this warning when I finish.):
Thanks all for your speculation, here is an example of $A_{n}$ derived from the spatial structure of ten samples, n=10.
        [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]   [,7]   [,8]   [,9]  [,10]
 [1,] 1.0000 0.9416 0.7284 0.7284 0.5834 0.5834 0.5834 0.0014 0.0000 0.0000
 [2,] 0.9416 1.0000 0.7284 0.7284 0.5834 0.5834 0.5834 0.0014 0.0000 0.0000
 [3,] 0.7284 0.7284 1.0000 0.9213 0.5834 0.5834 0.5834 0.0014 0.0000 0.0000
 [4,] 0.7284 0.7284 0.9213 1.0000 0.5834 0.5834 0.5834 0.0014 0.0000 0.0000
 [5,] 0.5834 0.5834 0.5834 0.5834 1.0000 0.9168 0.6186 0.0014 0.0000 0.0000
 [6,] 0.5834 0.5834 0.5834 0.5834 0.9168 1.0000 0.6186 0.0014 0.0000 0.0000
 [7,] 0.5834 0.5834 0.5834 0.5834 0.6186 0.6186 1.0000 0.0014 0.0000 0.0000
 [8,] 0.0014 0.0014 0.0014 0.0014 0.0014 0.0014 0.0014 1.0000 0.0000 0.0000
 [9,] 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 1.0000 0.8664
[10,] 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.8664 1.0000

While this "toy" example of $A_{n}$ above is given for demonstration purposes, to test the suggestion jbowman that I allow $\lambda$ to be negative, I'm going to use
A_n<-matrix(c(1,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.3,1,0.72,0.72,0.54,0.54,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.3,0.72,1,0.79,0.54,0.54,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.3,0.72,0.79,1,0.54,0.54,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.3,0.54,0.54,0.54,1,0.83,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.3,0.54,0.54,0.54,0.83,1,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,1,0.92,0.91,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.92,1,0.91,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.91,0.91,1,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,1,0.4,0.4,0.4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.4,1,0.6,0.6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.4,0.6,1,0.9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.4,0.6,0.9,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0.43,0.18,0.18,0.18,0.18,0.18,0.18,0.18,0.18,0.18,0.18,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.43,1,0.18,0.18,0.18,0.18,0.18,0.18,0.18,0.18,0.18,0.18,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.18,0.18,1,1,0.76,0.76,0.76,0.76,0.76,0.71,0.71,0.71,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.18,0.18,1,1,0.76,0.76,0.76,0.76,0.76,0.71,0.71,0.71,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.18,0.18,0.76,0.76,1,0.99,0.89,0.89,0.79,0.71,0.71,0.71,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.18,0.18,0.76,0.76,0.99,1,0.89,0.89,0.79,0.71,0.71,0.71,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.18,0.18,0.76,0.76,0.89,0.89,1,0.97,0.79,0.71,0.71,0.71,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.18,0.18,0.76,0.76,0.89,0.89,0.97,1,0.79,0.71,0.71,0.71,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.18,0.18,0.76,0.76,0.79,0.79,0.79,0.79,1,0.71,0.71,0.71,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.18,0.18,0.71,0.71,0.71,0.71,0.71,0.71,0.71,1,0.86,0.86,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.18,0.18,0.71,0.71,0.71,0.71,0.71,0.71,0.71,0.86,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.18,0.18,0.71,0.71,0.71,0.71,0.71,0.71,0.71,0.86,1,1),25,25)


where $A_{n}$ is (25 x 25) just like in jbowman's example below.  Thus I will run the following code:
A_n<-matrix(c(1,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.3,1,0.72,0.72,0.54,0.54,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.3,0.72,1,0.79,0.54,0.54,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.3,0.72,0.79,1,0.54,0.54,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.3,0.54,0.54,0.54,1,0.83,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.3,0.54,0.54,0.54,0.83,1,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,1,0.92,0.91,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.92,1,0.91,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.91,0.91,1,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,1,0.4,0.4,0.4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.4,1,0.6,0.6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.4,0.6,1,0.9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.4,0.6,0.9,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0.43,0.18,0.18,0.18,0.18,0.18,0.18,0.18,0.18,0.18,0.18,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.43,1,0.18,0.18,0.18,0.18,0.18,0.18,0.18,0.18,0.18,0.18,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.18,0.18,1,1,0.76,0.76,0.76,0.76,0.76,0.71,0.71,0.71,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.18,0.18,1,1,0.76,0.76,0.76,0.76,0.76,0.71,0.71,0.71,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.18,0.18,0.76,0.76,1,0.99,0.89,0.89,0.79,0.71,0.71,0.71,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.18,0.18,0.76,0.76,0.99,1,0.89,0.89,0.79,0.71,0.71,0.71,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.18,0.18,0.76,0.76,0.89,0.89,1,0.97,0.79,0.71,0.71,0.71,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.18,0.18,0.76,0.76,0.89,0.89,0.97,1,0.79,0.71,0.71,0.71,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.18,0.18,0.76,0.76,0.79,0.79,0.79,0.79,1,0.71,0.71,0.71,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.18,0.18,0.71,0.71,0.71,0.71,0.71,0.71,0.71,1,0.86,0.86,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.18,0.18,0.71,0.71,0.71,0.71,0.71,0.71,0.71,0.86,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.18,0.18,0.71,0.71,0.71,0.71,0.71,0.71,0.71,0.86,1,1),25,25)
I_n <- diag(1,25)
func <- function(lambda, x) {
    S <- lambda*A_n + (1-lambda)*I_n
    retval <- mvtnorm::dmvnorm(x, mean=rep(0,25), sigma=S, log=TRUE)
}
mle <- rep(0,1000)
mle2<- rep(0,1000)
for (i in seq_along(mle)) {
    x <- rnorm(25)
    res <- optimize(func, lower=0, upper=1, maximum=TRUE, x=x)
    mle[i] <- res$maximum
    # I think -0.14 is the correct "true" lower limit:
    res2<- optimize(func, lower=-0.14, upper=1, maximum=TRUE, x=x)
    mle2[i]<- res2$maximum
}
summary(mle)
summary(mle2)
hist(mle)
hist(mle2)

Notice that for my type of $A_{n}$ I can replicate the results shown in
this answer for my problem where $\lambda$ is constrained in $[0,1]$.   However, one potentially strange thing is that when I allow $\lambda$ to take on negative values, despite the data generating process using $\lambda$ equals zero, the actual mode of the estimate is the limiting negative value (-0.14 for this specific $A_{n}$ matrix), though the mean and median are both close to zero.
summary(mle)
#     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
#0.0000408 0.0000614 0.0000763 0.1007287 0.1293151 0.9183230 
summary(mle2)
#    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
#-0.13996 -0.12253 -0.03151  0.04491  0.12745  0.91830 




It was recently discussed/lamented in chat that investigators have decided to use Wilcoxon tests with sample sizes too small to give $p<0.05$ under any circumstances. That isn't the same as what you're doing, but, yes, some p-values can be impossible, with that serving as one example.

Any non-randomized test statistic based on realizations of random variables having at most countable supports will have at most a countable number of possible values.  Thus, any p-value computed from such a test statistic cannot have any possible value in the interval $[0,1].$ This is very apparent in nonparametric tests of small datasets (where the random values in question are ranks, signs, or limited to the data values).  In your case, because you generate data from a continuous unbounded distribution, I am inclined to suspect an error in the calculation.

I suspect that this is because the true value of the parameter $\lambda$ is on the boundary of the parameter space, which, as is well-known, messes up a lot of maximum likelihood estimator properties.  In your case, if $A_n$ differs substantially from the identity matrix - where "substantially" depends on the sample size -  I could well imagine the MLE actually is zero in a lot of cases.  Try a) finding something close to the smallest (most negative)  $\lambda$ for which the covariance matrix is PD, and b) relaxing the restriction on the lower bound of $\lambda$ in the obvious way...

Then the true value is in the interior of the parameter space, and the log-likelihood ratios will likely be more-or-less centered around 0, which is what they would converge to as $n \to \infty$.

... in the previous comment, I meant "...the estimates of $\lambda$ will likely be more-or-less centered around 0", apologies.

thanks jbowman, based on your terminology I found this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/648118/398015 which I think agrees with your answer.  But I am confused.  When the nice properties go away because of the null being on the boundary, is the validity of the likelihood ratio test one of those properties?  In the meanwhile I will take your advice and fit the model allowing lambda to be negative and see how it changes the distribution of estimated lambdas (I should be able to report back in a few hours)

It's still valid, it's just not got the same asymptotic distribution (so in a sense it's just a test statistic with a distribution.)  https://genepi.qimr.edu.au/contents/p/staff/CVPV114.pdf is of interest here.  I believe that in this case - one parameter, true value on the boundary - it's a 50-50 mixture of "0" and a $\chi^2(1)$ distribution (instead of the usual $\chi^2(1)$ itself.)

thank you! I understand if you don't have time to look, but do you think this paper is irrelevant to my problem then?  I don't really understand it, but it seems to be claiming bootstrapped MLE values cannot be trusted when the null hypothesis is on the boundary: http://dido.econ.yale.edu/~dwka/pub/p0994.pdf  I much appreciate it.

The LR test remains valid but the statistic no longer asymptotically has a chi-squared distribution.  Typically it's a mixture of a $\chi^2(0)$ distribution and what you would expect.

As others have mentioned, yes there are cases where some p-values are impossible.  But I don't think that is the case here.
It is also possible that there is an error in your calculations.  But it is also possible that you are just not generating enough bootstrap samples to see the small p-values.
If the true p-value for a given $\lambda$ is $0.001$, then there is a $0.63$ probability of seeing 0 out of 1,000 samples be less extreme then your observed data.  If you rerun your analysis using 9,999 or 99,999 bootstrap samples you will probably see some additional non-zero but very close to 0 p-values.  Or you could just increase your bootstrap samples to about 3,700 and report your 0 p-values as "p < 0.001" (with 95% confidence).

If $A_n$ differs substantially from the identity matrix - where "substantially" depends upon the sample size - the MLE of $\lambda$ will be driven to zero quite often, and your results will follow.
Conceptually, there are $n(n-1)/2$ distinct off-diagonal entries in $\lambda A_n + (1-\lambda) \mathbb{I}_n$, all of which, under the null hypothesis and data generating process, are equal to zero.  Even for modest $n$, that's a lot of parameters that are equal to zero and can be estimated as such simply by setting the single parameter $\hat{\lambda} = 0$.  With $n = 25$, we have 300 distinct off-diagonal entries in the covariance matrix; that's a lot of "pressure" on the MLE towards $\hat{\lambda} = 0$.
We can illustrate this effect with a simple experiment.  We generate 25 standard Gaussian variates, so $\mathbb{I_n}$ is the true covariance matrix.  We skip the estimation of $\sigma^2$, as it is equal to one, and by constructing $A_n$ so that the diagonal elements are all equal to one, the diagonal entries of the covariance matrix equal one regardless of $\lambda$.  We then find the MLE of $\lambda$ using a standard one-dimensional optimization routine, and repeat the experiment 1,000 times:
library(mvtnorm)
A_n <- diag(1,25) + 0.01
I_n <- diag(1,25)

func <- function(lambda, x) {
    S <- lambda*A_n + (1-lambda)*I_n
    retval <- dmvnorm(x, mean=rep(0,25), sigma=S, log=TRUE)
}

mle <- rep(0,1000)
for (i in seq_along(mle)) {
    x <- rnorm(25)
    res <- optimize(func, lower=0, upper=1, maximum=TRUE, x=x)
    mle[i] <- res$maximum
}

Now for the results:
> summary(mle)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
0.0000661 0.0000661 0.0000661 0.0791413 0.0481997 0.9999581 

Evidently, 0.000061 is as small a positive number as optimize can return; the default tolerance for testing convergence on my hardware is 0.00012207.  As we can see, the MLE is essentially equal to zero over half the time:
> mean(mle < 0.0000662)
[1] 0.695

In fact, we can reduce the off-diagonal elements of $A_n$ by several orders of magnitude while getting the same result.
Now let's redesign $A_n$ so that most of the off-diagonal elements are zero, i.e., it's closer to the identity matrix:
A_n <- diag(1,25) 
for (i in 1:5) A_n[i,i+1] <- A_n[i+1,i] <- 0.1

which results in:
> summary(mle)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
0.0000661 0.0000661 0.2166391 0.4853882 0.9999339 0.9999339 

with histogram:
$\lambda$" />
Clearly our results are critically dependent on $A_n$, and for $A_n$ with even a small number of non-zero off-diagonal elements, the tendency will be to push $\hat{\lambda}$ to zero or, perhaps, one.
Now for some simulation-based investigation of unbiasedness.  To do this, we set $\lambda = 0.4$, in the interior of the parameter space, and consider three sample sizes: $20, 100, 1000$.  We run the simulation 10,000 times for the $n=20$ case, 1,000 times for the $n = 100$ and $n=1000$ cases, making lunch while the last one is executing.  Our $A_n$ matrix is constructed as:
A_n <- diag(0.8,N) + 0.2 
I_n <- diag(1,N)
mu <- rep(0,N)
sigma <- 0.4*A_n + 0.6*I_n # lambda = 0.4

A summary version of the results is that in none of the three cases could a t-test reject the null hypothesis that $\lambda = 0.4$ at the 95% level of confidence.  As our sample sizes increased, the distribution of $\hat{\lambda}$ slowly became unimodal:



In a limited and informal way, bias does not really seem to be an issue; the real issue is the bimodal sampling distribution (with the modes at the extremes) of $\hat{\lambda}$ even for sample sizes in the hundreds.

wow. this looks very promising thank you. I think your analysis is completely correct, but I'm confused at the step of "so what do I do about it?"  Do I just carry on doing the normal likelihood ratio test?  Or maybe you have a better way I can study this problem?  The two things I would be most interested in are hypothesis testing and an unbiassed estimate of lambda.  So far my approaches have been, generate the null statistic with parametric bootstrap to test significance, and to estimate the true lambda value...

... my approach has been identify high correlation points and assume their correlation is actually one, so that any variation in these points is assumed to be due to a nugget effect, and then after measuring the nugget, conditional on that, finding the maximum likelihood estimate of $\sigma^2$ for $A_{n}$ which explains the full dataset. (this approach stems from the comments of https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/650189/398015 )


I don't think the normal LR test will work here, as the true value / null hypothesis is  on the boundary of the parameter space, which typically messes up the asymptotic distribution of the statistic.   2. I also wouldn't assume the correlation is as high as1; what will happen if you have a collection of three points with pairwise assumed correlations = 1 whose values don't support that?  3.  Does this mean you are, in effect,  estimating $A_n$ (albeit in a rough sort of way) in a pre-processing step?   ...  I'll have to think about this a little more... and review your previous post.


thxs, I'm testing the method for making the unbiassed estimate of $\lambda$ with sims now, I'll know whether it works or not by tomorrow.  As for the significance testing.  My hope was that by using parametric bootstrap, I wouldn't need to rely on any assumptions about asymptotic distributions.  Instead, I could simulate the likelihood ratio statistic.  It is actually how I discovered that $\lambda$ equals zero so frequently, because my distribution of p-values under the null is exactly 1 50% of the time, and then simulations are still running, so I do not know if the 5% threshold works.

also, I am curious, how did you know there would be "pressure" on the mle pushing it towards the limits?  I'm not sure I understand why this pressure exists. I understand the $n(n-1)/2$ number of entries thing, but why should the MLE prefer those entries be zero instead of some other value?

No, I never estimate the entries of $A_{n}$ because all the locations of the observed points are known.  In biology there is a well known formula for calculating $A_{n}$ from the genetic distances of the species being studied.  However, depending on the model of evolution, the expected covariance between two species could be described by the resulting matrix as $\lambda$ ranges from zero to one.

WRT "pressure" - because it appeared to me that the data generating process was assuming all those values were zero, so, in that case, the true values are zero, and the MLE of $\lambda$ will consequently tend to prefer $\lambda$ values that make the estimated values close to zero, i.e., small $\lambda$s.

Is your "pressure" hypothesis supported by the chart of mle2 I added to the question above which shows the MLE values of  $\lambda$ when it is allowed to be negative (to it's lower limit)?

I've added a section on unbiasedness, limited though it is.

thank you! just to clarify, even for n=1000, a t-test could not reject the null hypothesis that $\lambda=0.4$ when you used simulated data where $\lambda$ equalled 0.4, so that means the t-test gave the correct results?

Correct.  Simulation $\neq$ proof, of course, but it's indicative of something.
